# Phonegap - inserting variable into database

Tags: javascript, android, database, sqlite, cordova

I'm trying to insert variables values to a data base but it comes out as 'undefined'.
It is all inside device ready. I'm testing 1st with the variable 'absenceDateFrom'.

```
        var absenceType = document.getElementById('absenceType')
        var absenceText = document.getElementById('noteNewAbsence')
        var absenceDateFrom = document.getElementById('absenceFrom')
        var absenceDateTo = document.getElementById('absenceTo')

        db.transaction(
                function(tx) {        
                    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO absences (id,type,absenceFrom,absenceTo,note,aproved,picture) VALUES (" + id++  
                                                                                                                       + ",'" 
                                                                                                                       + String(absenceType.value)
                                                                                                                       + "','"
                                                                                                                       + absenceDateFrom.value.toString
                                                                                                                       + "','" 
                                                                                                                       + absenceDateTo.value.toString
                                                                                                                       + "','" 
                                                                                                                       + "random note (this works but if i put absenceText.value it comes out undefined also"
                                                                                                                       + "'," 
                                                                                                                       + "'true'"  
                                                                                                                       + "," 
                                                                                                                       + "'image.jpg'"  
                                                                                                                       + ")");
                }, transaction_error);
```

I also tried with '?' and [absenceDateFrom] in the end, like I saw on another answer and it still comes out undefined:

```
        var absenceType = document.getElementById('absenceType')
        var absenceText = document.getElementById('noteNewAbsence')
        var absenceDateFrom = document.getElementById('absenceFrom')
        var absenceDateTo = document.getElementById('absenceTo')

        db.transaction(
                function(tx) {        
                    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO absences (id,type,absenceFrom,absenceTo,note,aproved,picture) VALUES (" + id++  
                                                                                                                       + ",'" 
                                                                                                                       + String(absenceType.value)
                                                                                                                       + "',"
                                                                                                                       + "?"
                                                                                                                       + ",'" 
                                                                                                                       + absenceDateTo.value.toString
                                                                                                                       + "','" 
                                                                                                                       + "random note (this works but if i put absenceText.value it comes out undefined also"
                                                                                                                       + "'," 
                                                                                                                       + "'true'"  
                                                                                                                       + "," 
                                                                                                                       + "'image.jpg'"  
                                                                                                                       + ")", [absenceDateFrom.value] );
                }, transaction_error);
```

output:
http://prntscr.com/44eb31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the assumptions that I have made about datatypes of the variables.

```
Number id;
String type,absenceFrom,absenceTo,note,aproved,picture;
```

Also **aproved** variable seems to be typo error. Should it not be **approved**
I have modified your **tx()** call
If there are any errors in the insert call. check the output of the **errorInsert** call

```
db.transaction(
    function(tx) {
        var sqlStmt = "INSERT INTO absences (id,type,absenceFrom,absenceTo,note,aproved,picture) VALUES ("
            + (id++) + ","
            + "'" + String(type) + "',"
            + "'" + String(absenceDateFrom) + "',"
            + "'" + String(absenceDateTo) + "',"
            + "'" + "random note (this works but if i put absenceText.value it comes out undefined also" + "',"
            + "'" + "true" + "',"
            + "'" + "image.jpg" + "',"
            + ")";
        console.log("sqlStmt:"+sqlStmt);
        tx.executeSql(sqlStmt,successInsert,errorInsert);
        function errorInsert (err) {
            console.log("ERROR CODE:"+err.code+":Message:"+err.message);
        }
        function successInsert(tx, result) {
            console.log("SuccessInsert():Last inserted ID = " + result.insertId);
            console.log("SuccessInsert():rowsAffected: " + result.rowsAffected);
        }
    }, transaction_error);
```

Comment: problem was that the variables type,absenceFrom,absenceTo were input values and when i called the .value inside the string it came out undefined. Called the .value outside and it's working :)  your function successInsert helped me figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First: try to `console.log(absenceDateTo)` before inserting and be sure that the value is not undefined.

Second: In the line :

```
   absenceDateTo.value.toString
```

You are passing the function context but you should call the function instead.

```
   absenceDateTo.value.toString()
```

Try this ;)

Comment: fixed the toString() but still undefined :( when i print the value with console.log(absenceDateTo) before doing the transaction it comes out correct. i don't get this